# jQuery form processing and posting

Tags: jquery, forms, post

I am really trying to get somewhere with jQuery, but I just cannot get it to process forms.  Here is my (test) code:

```
<form id="form" >
    <input type="text" name="abc" />
    <input type="text" name="def"/>
    <input type="text" name="ghi"/>
    <input type="submit" name="try" id="try" />
</form>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#try").click(function() {
        $.post("process.php", $("#form").serialize());    
    });
});
```

As a simple test I am have this on process.php and if I access process php direct it works

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO testit (tryit) VALUES ('1')");
```

if I then try

```
$tryit = $_POST['abc'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO testit (tryit) VALUES ($tryit)");
```

i.e accessing the post variable abc nothing happens

Yes I do connect to the DB

Why does the jQuery not go to the page process.php?

The serialization works as I can see this in the browser

```
testit.php?abc=q345&def=345&ghi=2345&try=Submit+Query
```

What I really want to do is POST the form variables into the DB table, why can I not get it to work? either as above or by trying to post the variables?

Comment: Russell, we never figured out what happened with the other post you made on posting back a form.  Without knowing if one of the options worked for you, we have no way of knowing what's happening here.  Try solving one step at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").submit(function(){
        $.post("process.php", $("#form").serialize());    
    });
});
```