# jQuery form processing

Tags: forms, jquery

Does anybody know of a **simple** jQuery form processing tutorial that actually works?

I have a form I want to process via jQuery/Ajax nothing difficult in PHP but in jQuery and AJAX can I get it to work - no, all the tutorials are based round sending e-mails (or just lists of more lists of more lists of tutorials - hate those)

All I want to do is learn how to send a form via jQuery and AJAX to another page, save the data in a DB without having to leave the first page.  I have tried all sorts but nothing works properly.  Here is my form:

```
<form id="form">
<input type="text" name="abc" />
<input type="text" name="def"/>
<input type="text" name="ghi"/>
<input type="submit" name="try" id="try" />
</form>
```

Now what do I actually do?  Sounds silly I know (and I guess I'll get another -1 star for this question) but I will be honest a GOOD simple tutorial would be really useful not just to me but to the others.  I know php but jQuery/Ajax - just don't know/understand.  I will not be alone

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice, update your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326167/jquer-form-processing

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the good tutorials on how to **[submit forms using ajax and php](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajaxform.php)**.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) is a reference teaching how to submit forms via jQuery/AJAX. Have the form post to a PHP page to handle the form data.

In short, your jQuery code would look similar to this:

```
$("#form").submit( function()
{
    // Handle validation or any extra data here.
    // Return true if validation passed and the data should be posted
    // Return false if the form should not be submitted

    // You can also do any extra work here that you like before returning,
    // including changing something on the page or showing the user a message.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a cracking plugin for this:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/form/

It's as easy as:

```
$('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
    alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
});
```